# New UI Page that will display custom message in AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How to display the New UI(password expiry notification) page after sign-in.  The content of the UI is

A header with text   " Your Password will expire in next 14 days" (14..13...12.. 1)  and 2 Buttons Skip and Continue.   Continue should redirect to Password reset and Skip redirects to a Dashboard page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization

in the above link   Customize the default Azure AD B2C pages section had predefined pages but I can't fit my page content.

Is it possible to create My own page of custom content with custom policies? If yes please refer  me to the resource

Comment: Your quoted link is the correct UI customization tutorial page. Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by "can't fit my page content"?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

You can do the sign-in with the redirect to B2C login as usual.

Then it returns you, through the redirect_uri, to a password expiration page (or some othe page which forwards to the right place) that you host where you can get the expiration date from B2C with a [Graph Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call (probably you have to save the date to a [User Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow), as I don't see it in the [built-in attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes)) and then calculate and present the remaining days.

Also in your change password custom policy you can set your expirationDate custom user attribute to a new value.

The Continue button can do a redirection to the password change policy while the Skip can get the user to whatever page you want.